# Grid + UiBinder : Setting row level styles

Tags: gwt, uibinder

```
...........
.........
<g:row styleName="OddNumberRow">
....
....
</g:row>
<g:row styleName="EvenNumberRow">
....
....
</g:row>
...........
...........
```

The above approach is not working. In other words, the "tr" elements in the generated html do not have any class names at all. A back up option would be to inject styles into these rows from the UiBinder's constructors (using getRowFormatter.addStyleName) but 
I do not want to take that route for now.(I wanna try to  reserve the code that goes into the UiBinder java class for event handling purposes only. )

Any thoughts/pointers would be much appreciated.

Note: Cross posted at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/yGRUkpcpBzU

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this does not work. I have also tried adding the style to *g:customCell*, which does not work either.

The only way I can think of is using a *SimplePanel* to wrap your content in:

```
<g:row>
  <g:customCell>
    <g:SimplePanel width="100%" height="100%" styleName="OddNumberRow">
      <g:Label>Content</g:Label>
    </g:SimplePanel>
  </g:customCell>
</g:row>
<g:row>
  <g:customCell>
    <g:SimplePanel width="100%" height="100%"  styleName="EvenNumberRow">
      <g:Label>Content</g:Label>
    </g:SimplePanel>
  </g:customCell>
</g:row>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GWT [has been updated](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/yGRUkpcpBzU/nrOZ0M_wyn0J) to understand `styleName=foo` directly on `<gwt:cell>` and `<gwt:row>` elements.

Your example code should now do what you expect :)